# Foreach returned $variable[] select from database and combine values

Tags: php, mysql

I have tried this around a couple of ways and different manners but no luck. (also searched for different solutions) I am sure I'm just missing something.

I have the following code:

```
$variable = returned array eg. 7, 8, 9;
foreach($variable as $entry_id){
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE entry_id=$entry_id") or die (mysql_error());
    while($row = mysql_fethc_array($query)){
        $qty = $row['quantity'];
        $combination = array_combine($qty);
    }
}
```

Everything works and the correct quantities are returned (on testing) but the combinations are not correct. Currently the combinations - of each entry_id - is combined with the next one.

Instead of receiveing eg.

```
$entry_id(7) = 15;
$entry_id(8) = 26;
$entry_id(9) = 58;
```

I am getting:

```
$entry_id(7) = 15;
$entry_id(8) = 41;
$entry_id(9) = 99;
```

The table structure would look something like this:

```
entry_id | quantity
7        | 5
7        | 5
9        | 29
8        | 26
7        | 5
9        | 29
```

Comment: Why don't you just use a SQL `GROUP BY`? For example : `SELECT entry_id, SUM(quantity) FROM table WHERE entry_id=$entry_id GROUP BY $entry_id`, you only have to parse one result then. By the way, you really should use something like PDO instead of creating your query manually.

Comment: The `GROUP BY` in my previous comment is a bit useless because of the `WHERE` clause. You can do even better and get all your sums in one database call : `SELECT entry_id, SUM(quantity) AS total FROM table WHERE entry_id IN (7, 8, 9) GROUP BY $entry_id`, the construction of the IN array is left as an exercise ;-)